# "The page you requested is invalid" when trying to sign into Google ..for import Gmail Contacts

Tags: javascript

I add the external script in head
 http://www.google.com/jsapi
Body Part:

```
    google.load("gdata", "1.s");
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function (){
        if(window.location.hash=="") {
            if(!checkLogin()){
                logMeIn();
            } else {
                var feedUrl = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full";
                query = new google.gdata.contacts.ContactQuery(feedUrl);
                query.setMaxResults(5000);
                myService = new google.gdata.contacts.ContactsService('exampleCo-exampleApp-1.0');
                myService.getContactFeed(query, function(result) {
                        document.cookie="g314-scope-0=";
                            window.opener.parseGmailContacts(result.feed.entry);
                    close();
                    }, function(e){
                        alert(e.cause ? e.cause.statusText : e.message);
                });
            }
        }
    });
    function logMeIn() {
        scope = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds";
        var token = google.accounts.user.login(scope);
    }
    function logMeOut() {
        google.accounts.user.logout();
    }
    function checkLogin(){
        scope = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/";
        var token = google.accounts.user.checkLogin(scope);
        return token;
    }
```

after page open it goes to https://accounts.google.com/AuthSubRequestJS?session=1&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fm8%2Ffeeds&next=http%3A%2F%2Fmaharashtratimes.indiatimes.com%2Fsocial_gmail.cms
and it;shown The page you requested is invalid. Please help.................